# Gitlab runner shows "command not found" even though using the proper docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, aws-cli, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using the `fstab/aws-cli` docker image to run `aws s3 sync` command in the gitlab shared runner.

I have added the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` variables in the `Secret Variables` section of the Gitlab repo. 
Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
master:
 type: deploy
 environment: master
 image: fstab/aws-cli
 script:
  - aws s3 sync . s3://aws-website-xxxxxxx --exclude ".git/*" --exclude ".vscode/*" --exclude ".DS_Store/*" --exclude ".DS_Store" --cache-control "max-age=120000" --delete
only:
 - master
```

But I get this error.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.6.0 (a3543a27)
  on docker-auto-scale 4e4528ca
Using Docker executor with image fstab/aws-cli ...
Pulling docker image fstab/aws-cli ...
Using docker image sha256:07971d88854000e2b123d27ae2baf8ffbcb3de299574e767c5c16de9178912f8 for fstab/aws-cli ...
Running on runner-4e4528ca-project-2805534-concurrent-0 via runner-4e4528ca-srm-1522761030-89416d8e...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/joyn/soyou-website'...
Checking out 9e4d298b as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
$ aws s3 sync . s3://aws-website-xxxxxxxx --exclude ".git/*" --exclude ".vscode/*" --exclude ".DS_Store/*" --exclude ".DS_Store" --cache-control "max-age=120000" --delete
/bin/bash: line 69: aws: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Unable to figure out whats wrong. Pointing out the problem would be of great help.

Comment: Could you share the Dockerfile of `fstab/aws-cli`?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/fstab/aws-cli/~/dockerfile/

Comment: got it working with another image apparently https://hub.docker.com/r/garland/aws-cli-docker/

Comment: Probably the image doesn't work properly anymore. It's been unmaintained for 2 years.

Comment: But would like to know why it didn't work with fstab/aws-cli image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with https://hub.docker.com/r/garland/aws-cli-docker/ docker image.